# what is the meaning of ".clone" in linux kernel dumpstack?

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel

stack trace example:

```
[<e50ff630>] adf_os_mem_alloc_outline+0x50/0x60 [adf]
[<e50f4d20>] amalloc_private+0x40/0x80 [asf]
[<e53f6508>] ieee80211_scan_entry_update.clone.2+0xac0/0xe18 [umac]
[<e53f7080>] ieee80211_scan_table_update+0x41c/0x5b8 [umac]
[<e53d0b98>] ieee80211_update_beacon+0x30/0x80 [umac]
[<e53d0dec>] ieee80211_recv_mgmt+0x204/0x18a4 [umac]
[<e5404cc8>] ieee80211_input+0x23c/0x1484 [umac]
[<e5405fe8>] ieee80211_input_all+0xd8/0x158 [umac]
[<e53c4abc>] ath_net80211_rx+0x764/0x77c [umac]
[<e528f474>] ath_rx_indicate+0x60/0xc8 [ath_dev]
[<e527bd2c>] ath_rx_process+0x1d4/0x5f8 [ath_dev]
[<e528c080>] ath_rx_handler+0x408/0x5cc [ath_dev]
[<e528c284>] ath_rx_edma_tasklet+0x40/0x68 [ath_dev]
[<e528f404>] ath_handle_rx_intr+0x28/0x38 [ath_dev]
[<e52714dc>] ath_handle_intr+0x25c/0x8c0 [ath_dev]
[<e5409284>] ath_tasklet+0x24/0x34 [umac]
```

what is the meaning of **ieee80211_scan_entry_update.clone.2**?

the source code ofcourse contain only ieee80211_scan_entry_update() function.

why gcc making clone functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of a compiler, [function cloning](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=844097) is creating several copies of a function with some modifications.

For example, if the compiler discovers that a function is called many different times with the same initial parameter, it may clone the function to produce a version which takes one less parameter, and then change all the callers to call the clone.